# How to hide text field in Html File Upload

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to hide the text field portion of a standard html file upload tag

for example

```
<input type="file" name="somename" size="chars">
```

This generates obviously a text field and next to that field is a browse button... I want to hide the text field part but keep the button.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd recommend hiding the whole thing and putting a separate button object which, when clicked, will end up clicking the input's browse button.

You can do this with CSS and javascript -- [check out this article](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom) (actually the second time I've used this reference today).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in IE. IE outputs an error once the upload is started.

Comment: Works as of IE10. IE9 and below does not allow tempering the file input field by JS.

Comment: IE 10 today blocks with access denied when delegating clicks from one button to the file input element, better to get an opacity = 0 overlaid on top of your ui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624863/ie10-must-click-2-times-to-submit-form-after-choosing-a-file-to-upload

Answer (score 35):

This will surely work i have used it in my projects.I hope this helps :)

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" />
<input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
```

Comment: Great just what I needed ;)

Comment: This solution will not degrade gracefully when JS is disabled.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way as not mentioned in any answer would be to use a `label` for the `input`.

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile">
<label for="myFile">Choose your file</label>

input[type="file"] { display: none; }
```

Using `label` will be useful because clicking on the label is clicking on the input.
This will only work when input's `id` is equal to label's `for` attribute.

Comment: Best part is that you do not have to put any extra logic in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an image as a background for the button.
That worked for me, a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

The `file` input button is extremely difficult to style and manipulate, mainly for security reasons.

If you really need to customize your upload button, I recommend a Flash based uploader like [**SWFUpload**](http://www.swfupload.org) or [**Uploadify**](http://www.uploadify.com/) that enables you to use a custom image as button, display a progress bar, and other things.

However, its basic philosophy differs from just embedding a control into a form. The uploading process takes place separately. Make sure you check out first whether this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatly I am locked into the way my client designed the site.. which is a simple image button to bring up the file dialog.

Comment: This could be done quite reliably using a Flash uploader. But if Shaun Inman's article works and degrades gracefully, that should do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="file"] { outline: none; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top:0; clip: rect(0 265px 22px 155px);  } /* Hide input field */
@-moz-document url-prefix()
  {
  input[type="file"] { clip: rect(0, 265px, 22px, 125px);  } /* Mozilla */
  }
* > /**/ input[type="file"], x:-webkit-any-link { clip: rect(0, 86px, 22px, 0); } /* Webkit */
```

This will do the same without JavaScript, but requires absolute positioning to use the `clip` property.

**References**

- [Custom Upload Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822847/1113772)
- [CSS Wikibook: Clipping](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Clipping)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZ5ME/)

**Pure css and html**

The trick is to use a button above the input file button.

Plus, you should set

```
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```

to the input file.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly hide the whole element and show a button or link instead. This is rather easy.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileupload" style="width:200px; display:none;" onchange="submitmyform();" />
<input type="button" value="Select an Image" onclick="$('#fileupload').click();" />
```

The file upload element is hidden. The button will fire the click event and shows the file browser window. On selecting a file, the change event is fired and this can submit a form or call a script function, whatsoever.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, have a look at this plugin - https://github.com/ajaxray/bootstrap-file-field

It will display the file input field as a bootstrap button and will show selected file names beautifully. Additionally, you can set various restrictions using simple data-attributes or settings in js.
e,g, `data-file-types="image/jpeg,image/png"` will restrict selecting file types except jpg and png images.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css to your input

```
    font-size: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I get inspired by @shiba and here is solution in Angular 9:

```
    <input type="file" [id]="inputId" class="form-control" [style.display]="'none'"
        [accept]="acceptedDocumentTypes" [multiple]="true" #fileInput
        (change)="fileChange($event)" (blur)="onTouched()">

    <input type="button" class="form-control" value="Browse..." (click)="fileInput.click()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set it's content to empty string
like this :

```
<input type="file" name="somename" size="chars" class="mycustominput">
```

and in your css file :

```
.mycustominput:after{
    content:""!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the text behind the button changing the buttons width to 100% using the webkit-class. The button will then overlap the `<span>` behind itself on the shadow-root.

There is no need to apply any opacity, transparency or hidden attribute to the button, it's just a bit different to style compared to other objects and this will keep the localisation of the form element alive.

This will do the trick and [is supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_file-selector-button) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button)):

```css
input[type=file]::-ms-browse { /* legacy edge */
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=file]::file-selector-button { /* standard */
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button { /* webkit */
  width: 100%;
}
```