# CSS file-input hide path

Tags: css, input-type-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide text field in Html File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034826/how-to-hide-text-field-in-html-file-upload)

Hi!Is it possible to hide the input-file path keeping just the browse button?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the file input isn't style-able, and it shows differently in each browser. So any solutions are sort of hacky, to say the least.

One solution is to place an image behind the input, and setting it's opacity to 0. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) for the tutorial that I follow.