# Input type="file" works badly in firefox 23.0.1

Tags: html, firefox

I have usual form, there are some input type="file" elements. Strange, but they don't work very well in Firefox 23.0.1. They work only on second click (and sometimes on first). In all other browsers (didn't test in prev Firefox though) all is perfectly OK.

```
<div>
    <label>User files</label>
    <div>
        No user files
        <br />
        <input type="file" class="save-my-data-btn btn-min userfiles" name="userfiles[]" id="ufirstFile" />
        <div class="msgerr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Manager files</label>
    <div>
        No manager files
        <br />
        <input type="file" class="save-my-data-btn btn-min adminfiles" name="adminfiles[]" id="afirstFile" />
        <div class="msgerr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Did someone encountered the same issue?

Here is css

```
    .btn-min {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 10px 3px;
}
.save-my-data-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgb(190, 226, 249) inset;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(208, 228, 241) 5%, rgb(161, 191, 219) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(161, 191, 219);
    border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(113, 136, 167);
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(41, 85, 126);
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgb(224, 224, 224);
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What CSS have you got associated with it, as I have a hunch that some CSS is blocking part of the input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16080910/1446146), It will help in customising a button and use it as a file input form your form, and it will look pretty much the same on all browsers

Comment: Shouldn't you have flagged the question as a duplicate, instead of linking to the other SO question as your answer?

Comment: the other question is about customising file inputs in general, this question is about how `firefox` render file inputs and how can you fix it for that browser, i put this answer out there and if anyone has an a better answer for this question better related to this question can still post it.

Comment: thanks! I looked at the answer and tried adding position: relative to input css. It worked!