# Uploading images with customizing <a></a> in html

Tags: javascript, html, upload

I'm a newbie in html and trying to upload image to my homepage.

I already set up the uploading part like below in html,

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li>
       <form action="/upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" style="max-width: 30%; max-height: 50%;"  name="upFile" id="upFile" onchange="getCmaFileView(this,'name')" target="dropzone_1">
         <input type="submit" name="Upload" >
       </form>
     </li>
     <li>
       <form action="/jsondata", method="get", id="jsd", enctype="multipart/form-data"  ></form>
     </li>
     <li><a onclick="save2()" id="imageSave">Save</a></li>
  </ul>
```

However, it shows a button like old-fashioned typical button like below,

[image]

and I want it to make my own customized button using  with clicking..

I tried to find in google, but they used `<div>` instead of `<form>` of mine..
So I posted here [customize the file button for image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080644/customize-the-file-button-for-image-upload)

I know this might be a stupid question, but I just want to learn!

How can I make that...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for editing! :) I was kinda in a daze.. :'(

Comment: Why does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461252/custom-upload-button not work for you?

Comment: @mplungjan nope.. doesn't work.. made a button with using <a> and followed answer from the link but doesn't appear anything when I click the <a></a>

Comment: So don't use A, use a label or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example how to style your upload button. Basically you have to hide your html input.

```css
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-success">
    <span>Click to upload new file</span>
    <input type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```