# Does <label> for attribute has to be unique?

Tags: html, validation

Can I have two labels with the same `for` value? Example:

```
<label for="foo">Outer label</label>
<div class="foo-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="foo" />
    <label for="foo">Inner label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: As a sidenote you can avoid it by putting it inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `for` attribute links a control to an `input`, there is, so far as I know, no limit to the number of elements that can link to one `input`, so long as the `id` of that `input` (or `textarea`, `select`, etc) is unique.

For example, in the following demo *both* `label` elements will trigger the change (check/uncheck) of the checkbox `input` element:

```
<label for="foo">Outer label</label>
<div class="foo-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test" id="foo" />
    <label for="foo">Inner label</label>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R9XsK/).

This can be useful for adding error messages (post-validation, for example) that explicitly link to, or otherwise identify, the element in which there's an error, without overriding/replacing the pre-existing `label` for that element.

Unfortunately there is, so far as I've *yet found*, no reference or documentation that explicitly allows an `input` (or similar element) to linked to only one control; however [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)'s entry for [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) does state that:

> The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.

Comment: `so far as I know` - reference please?

Comment: There's no explicit reference to say only one element must be linked-to by only one `label`'s `for` attribute (or I would have deliberately *cited* that reference to complete the answer). The *lack* of an explicit restriction, however, is what makes me believe it's valid. There are, for example, explicit restrictions placed on duplicate `id`s, nonesuch exists for the `for` attribute of a `label`, however.

Comment: In addition it should be noted that [labelable elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#category-label), such as the `input`, `button` and `select` elements, hava a [`labels`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-lfe-labels) IDL attribute (i.e. a `labels` property in common terminology), which is a node list of all the elements which are the labels of that element.