# Create a "Fake Button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making a form, and as you know some some types of forms are harder to style than others. For instance `<input type="file">`, I'd like to somehow make a fake button so when you click the fake button, it's really clicking the input button.

I've tried:

```
$("#inputFile").click();
```

But as you suspect, this didn't work.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/14636214755/making-file-inputs-a-pleasure-to-look-at

Comment: Obviously, the ability of a browser to upload local files to a website, under the control of that website and without the user's knowledge, is deliberately restricted.

Comment: The answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461252/custom-upload-button/6461518#6461518 does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger click event of input element using **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** when click on the button:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uv8jj/)**

Comment: Hmmm, this is more simple than I thought.

Comment: I haven't tried this technique. Obviously the button is easier to style than input type file. Thank you!

Comment: It is. But I ain't certain if the file will be fetched correctly using this.

Comment: @witherwind I'm pretty sure it will, because it's not getting the file from the `<button>`, it's still getting the file from `<input>`.

Comment: I meant, I wasn't sure at first that's why I didn't answer. But I tested it and worked.

Answer (score 0):

@felix's answer is right. In addition,

The example is given on [jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/click/) as well .

Please check the 3rd example

> We can also trigger the event when a different element is clicked:

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
    $( "#target" ).click();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of what you are looking for.

[Custom Upload Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461252/custom-upload-button/6461518#6461518)

I repeat the answer here:

The trick is to turn the opacity of the input to 0 and then change the background underneath it to the button style that you want.

Given this html:

```
<div class="file_button_container"><input type="file" /></div>
```

Use this css:

```
  .file_button_container,
  .file_button_container input {
       height: 47px;
       width: 263px;
   }

   .file_button_container {
       background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT5AB.png) left top no-repeat;
   }

   .file_button_container input {
       opacity: 0;
   }
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/t6EKv/1/

Comment: This does look like a good technique, but I had already excepted a different answer.

Comment: Anyone have an idea why I got the down vote? For posting an alternative?