# Jquery Image on Hover make input type file

Tags: html, css

While I hover the icon shows over image. But I want to display the icon like this

And while i click, it should allow to browse files like
[image]

```
<input type ='file'>
```

How can I do this?

I tried like putting the file tag to all, but it didn't worked. How can I do this?

```css
.profile-img-container {
  position: absolute;
  width:50%;
}

.profile-img-container img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 501;
}

.profile-img-container img:hover + i {
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
}

.profile-img-container i {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:43%;
  margin-top:40%;
}

.profile-img-container img {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="profile-img-container">
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive" />
  <i class="fa fa-upload fa-5x"></i>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLb3thhy/)

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more code than that

Comment: I have give the fiddle there you can see it

Comment: If I understand it correctly you actually want to make this image act as file upload. If so you might consider this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461252/custom-upload-button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an `input[type="file"]` to your code and make it invisible. Also, so it takes all the `img` place, set it `position` to `absolute` and all the other styles so it take all the place.

Like this:

```css
.profile-img-container {
  position: absolute;
  /*width:50%;*/
  /*border-radius:50%;*/
  overflow:hidden;
}

.profile-img-container img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 501;
}

.profile-img-container img:hover + i {
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
}

.profile-img-container .icon-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  padding:5px;
}

/*.profile-img-container img {
position:absolute;
}*/

/*.profile-img-container {
  position:relative;
}*/

input[type="file"] {
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="profile-img-container img-circle">
  <input type="file" />
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive" />
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should add a input file in your code but make it invisible then you can get file browse with jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<input id='uploadfile' type ='file'>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.profile-img-container img').click(function(){
    $('#uploadfile').click();
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLb3thhy/1/)**

**Second way for future questions:**

```
<input id='uploadfile' type ='file'>

input#uploadfile {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png');
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 23.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLdb0gbg/)**

Comment: thanks, how can i make the upload icon always visible ?

Comment: your welcome, if I understand right, see this example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sLb3thhy/3/)