# Dynamically creating file inputs in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-upload, cross-browser

The code below dynamically creates a file input once my custom button is clicked generating a file input with a name of photo[] and an id of photo'x' (x as a variable). The code is working fine with all the browsers except the almighty IE. In IE i can click my custom upload button add a file and when i submit the form, the file input will be cleared. It will submit the form but the file input would be blank. But it works well with other browsers.

is this a bug? or a security thingy? if it is, how can i fix this problem?

```
var x = 0;
addFile = function(addFileButton) {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var box = document.createElement('input');
    box.type = 'file';
    box.name = 'photo[]';
    box.id = 'photo' + x;
    box.style.cssText = 'position:absolute; top:-200px;';
    box.onchange = function() {
        checkFileDup(this.value, x - 1);
    };
    form.appendChild(box);
    jQuery("#photo" + x).trigger('click');
    x++;
}
```

Comment: You're using `jQuery` only for triggering a `click` event?

Comment: Yes, will that affect the code?

Comment: It would make it easier - that's all :)

Comment: It's a security feature. To workaround it, you have add box.onclick = function... to capture the text during the click events in IE, so you can validate it before the change event.

Comment: @PaulSweatte thanks for ur reply. Actually I can already validate everything but the only problem i have is when i submit the form, the file input clears its content as a result the submitted file is gone any work around with this issue? if box.onclick = function? what should i do inside the function? sorry i'm still a newbie with javascript and jquery. Thanks

Comment: You have to copy the file value to a dummy input field and layer that over the file input using absolute positioning to [fake it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034826/how-to-hide-text-field-in-html-file-upload).

Comment: @PaulSweatte thanks paul i did your advice but i does not get the file from the user. It only gets the file path. :(

Comment: Try different selectors such as jQuery("input[type='file']").val() or add a class to the input and reference by class name. There's a [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11983) in IE which makes the event handlers inconsistent, so you have to capture both the change and the click events to workaround it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a issue of IE, input[type=file] created via javascript are not submitable through form.

My solution is to make a bundle of hidden input[type=file] elements in the page and make them visible when required.