# IE10 - Must click 2 times to submit form after choosing a file to upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, input, internet-explorer-10

In a form I have a file input skinned with jquery and css and a submit button.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input style="width:150px" type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="40000"/>
  <div class="l-input-file">
    <input style="margin-bottom: 0px" type="file" id="myInput" name="myInput" size="16" />
  </div>
  <div><button type="submit" class="btn-black">Continuer</button></div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CsL9t/

The matter here appear only on IE10: After a file has been selected the submit button must be clicked 2 times to be able to submit the form.

I tried forcing the focus on the button when the file input change but it doesn't help.

I tried triggering the click using jQuery,

```
jQuery('#myInput').parents('form').find("button[type='submit']").click();
```

but I received 2 times the message 'access denied' before submitting the third time.

Any input or advice will be strongly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `$input.trigger('click');` is the issue. Triggering a click event on a file input taints a file input in IE.

Comment: What do you mean by "taints" exactly ?

Comment: Thanks @Musa. Indeed I removed the trigger click on the input file and just let it over the new button with ```opacity:0;```

Comment: @Musa Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$input.trigger('click');` is what causes the access denied error.
Triggering a click event on a file input taints a file input in IE preventing(to some extent) you from submitting the form or using it with a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

See also [getting access is denied error on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935001/getting-access-is-denied-error-on-ie8/4335390#4335390)