# How to put "No file chosen" text under a button

Tags: html, css

I need it to be under not next to the button. Is there any easy way to do that?

```
<input type="file" size="45">
```

Comment: Show your code that you done  until now (HTML,CSS)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The goal of this website isn't to write code for you, but to help you solve issues with your current code. Can you please provide us some code with some attempts you've made?

Comment: The text is automatically generated <br> can't help me

Comment: That isn't even an attempt... Did you tried some CSS or other HTML or even a few lines of Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

How about a solution like this

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML=this.value;"/>
<input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
<p>no file chosen</p>
```

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/366tjfvn/1/

ref: [How to hide text field in Html File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034826/how-to-hide-text-field-in-html-file-upload)

Updated thanks to: Ismael Miguel

Comment: The only thing now would be an `onchange` event in the file input to update the `<p>`

Comment: Try this: `<input type="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML=this.value;"/>`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code snippet:

Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <label style="width: 33px; display: inline-block;">Path : </label>
                <input type="text" id="UploadTextBox" readonly="readonly" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px; width: 300px; height: 18px; background-color: white;" />
                <input type="file" id="BtnBrowseHidden" name="files" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 15px;" />
                <label for="BtnBrowseHidden" id="LblBrowse" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 15px;">
                    Browse
                </label>
                <input type="submit" id="BtnUpload" value="Upload" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 15px;" />
            }
        <div>
            <label id="ErrorMessage" style="display: none; text-align: center; width: 200px; margin-left: 345px;"></label>
        </div>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnBrowseHidden').hide();
        $("#BtnBrowseHidden").change(function () {
            var Value = $(this).val();
            $('#UploadTextBox').val(Value);

            if (Value != "") {
                var extesion = /[^.]+$/.exec(Value);
                if (extesion[0] != "xlsx" && extesion[0] != "xls") {
                    //Please upload Excel file.
                    $("#ErrorMessage").html("Please upload Excel file.");
                    $("#ErrorMessage").css('color', 'red');
                    $("#ErrorMessage").show();
                    document.getElementById("BtnUpload").disabled = true;
                }
                else {
                    $("#ErrorMessage").html("");
                    $("#ErrorMessage").hide();
                    document.getElementById("BtnUpload").disabled = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                    $("#ErrorMessage").html("No File choosen.");
                    $("#ErrorMessage").css('color', 'red');
                    $("#ErrorMessage").show();
                 }
            return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It can be more useful if it comes with some explanation with the code.